# Granting AWS Config access to the Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

I would like to create the AWS Config access grant to the Amazon S3 Bucket and the policy is provided below that I write according to the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AWSConfigBucketPermissionsCheck",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
         "config.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::targetBucketName"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AWSConfigBucketExistenceCheck",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "config.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::targetBucketName"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AWSConfigBucketDelivery",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
         "config.amazonaws.com"    
        ]
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::targetBucketName/[optional] prefix/AWSLogs/sourceAccountID-WithoutHyphens/Config/*",
      "Condition": { 
        "StringEquals": { 
          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to know about the part provided below:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::targetBucketName/[optional] prefix/AWSLogs/sourceAccountID-WithoutHyphens/Config/*",
```

Whats the meaning of the `prefix` and how do I fill the `prefix/AWSLogs/sourceAccountID-WithoutHyphens/Config/*` part of the policy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix is what you define when you configure logging to S3. This is optional. Config writes the logs to S3 bucket using a standard path/key format which is "prefix/AWSLogs/sourceAccountID-WithoutHyphens/Config/*".

If you configure Config logging to S3 from console, you won't have to worry about the bucket policy as it will be created automatically. You simply give the bucket name and optional prefix.